# Defining Cauchy principal value in MATLAB (or Scilab/Maple)?

Tags: matlab, computational-physics, octave, maple

How to define a variable which is an integral involving cauchy principal value inside in any computer programming language? I want to know how to break down the procedure step by step from a computational science viewpoint.

This is the integral I encounter:
$S(\omega') = \int_0^\infty d \omega \frac{1}{\omega} \left( \mathcal{P} \left( \frac{1%
}{\omega' - \omega} \right) + \mathcal{P} \left( 
\frac{1}{\omega' + \omega} \right) \right) \ $

The LHS is a function of `w'`. The RHS is a function of `w'`. For example, `x(t) = 2t+1` defines the variable `x` in terms of `t`. `t = 1` means `x = 3`. 
For example in Matlab:

```
t = 1;
x = 2t + 1;
```

Now I want to define the variable `S` in terms of `w'`. For example,

```
w' = 1;
S = 2w' + 1; %<----(*) But what is S in terms of w' in my question?
```

then `S = 3` here. But it is not such a simple expression here. I need the expression of `S` or set up the integral on the R.H.S so I can get the expression of `S` in terms of `w'` like in line (*). For example in Matlab, is it needed to do it using `sym` (symbolic) or do I have to do it by fourier transform `fourier`?

Note that the R.H.S is a definite integral of `w`. But since it will disappear, `w'` is the only variable of `S` here.

Or to cut off the question into parts of just defining Cauchy principal value. I browse in matlab documentation http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/int.html

`int(1/(x - 1), x, 0, 2, 'PrincipalValue', true)` is what I encountered. But now I am not calculating improper integral. I want to define the Cauchy principal value of $$\frac{1}{x}$$ as in complex analysis and distribution. i.e. $$P\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = \lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0^+} \left[\int_a^{b-\varepsilon} 1/x\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{b+\varepsilon}^c 1/x\,\mathrm{d}x\right]$$.

Related question:
[Sokhotski–Plemelj theorem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275657/python-find-principal-value-of-an-integral-numerically)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in maple like this.

First you need to specifiy the lower and upper limits. `a`, `b`, and `c`.

For normal/primitive integration, we use

```
int(1/x, x = a .. c);
```

Now to find the Cauchy Principal Value, there is built-in option in maple `int`,

```
int(1/x, x = a .. c, 'CauchyPrincipalValue');
```

But if you actually want type in yourself then

```
Limit(Int(1/x, x = a .. b-epsilon)+Int(1/x, x = b+epsilon .. c), epsilon = 0, right);
```